# MySQL syntax error using python to add column to a table

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

The code i have is:

```
for key in keys:
    cursor.execute("""
                    ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD %s VARCHAR(40)
                    """, key)
```

I get a error telling me my syntax is wrong. When I replace the %s with a actual string the syntax error goes away.

```
for key in keys:
    cursor.execute("""
                    ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD myColumn VARCHAR(40)
                    """)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you do the replacement before feeding it?

```
query = "ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD %s VARCHAR(40)" % (key)
cursor.execute( query )
```

Comment: Specifically, there is a `,` where there should be a `%`! heh.

Comment: I am not surprised MySQL does not let you create a column named %s.

Comment: TO katrielalex: the , is correct. I have it working in other instances.

Comment: Actually, all Python SQL connectors are supposed to be used the way posted in the question, rather than this way - to shield against SQL injections. The substituition inside the cursor.execute method adds''quotes for that - and that causes the error

Comment: @meder: reread the 2nd sentence of @jsbueno's comment! effect is `... ADD 'myColumn' VARCHAR...` which is not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: Ah, my bad. OP should select @John Machin's answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bit of confusion going here, for several reasons:

(1) mySQL uses the `%` as a parameter marker -- easily confused with the `%` in Python's `string % (data1, data2, etc)`

(2) some people seem not to be aware that parameter markers can be used only where an *expression* can be used in SQL syntax -- this excludes table names, column names, function names, keywords, etc

(3) code-golf onelinerism

Required SQL: `ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD myColumn VARCHAR(40)`

Using a parameter doesn't work:

```
key = "myColumn"
sql = "ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD %s VARCHAR(40)" # col name not OK as parm
cursor.execute(sql, (key, ))
```

You need to build an acceptable SQL statement, using e.g. Python string formatting:

```
key = "myColumn"
sql = "ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD %s VARCHAR(40)" % key
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

when cursor.execute() replace %s in a query string it adds ' ' to the argument values supplied...so when you do

```
key = 'abc'
cursor.execute("""
                ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD %s VARCHAR(40)
                """, key)
```

the query executed is

```
ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD 'abc' VARCHAR(40)
```

to which mysql will throw a syntax error coz the column names, table names can be in `` but not ' '

so this will work

```
query = "ALTER TABLE segment_table ADD %s VARCHAR(40)" % (key)
```