# How can I add a column with mySQLdb in python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now and found this solution :

`colName = "nameHere"
try:
    c.execute('ALTER TABLE upload ADD %s INT(15);',(colName))
except:
    pass`

This apparently should work but I get the following error :

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'nameHere' in 'field list'")`

Not knowing the column seems logical since I'm trying to create that column.

Have I made a syntax mistake so enormous that I can't see it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039067/1023432 for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
query = "ALTER TABLE upload ADD %s INT(15)" % (colName)
c.execute( query )
```

Comment: This is wonderfully simple AND it works. It's also what I've been doing for every other query and I hadn't even thought of doing the same with this one.