# Adding columns in mySQL Workbench Model using Shell Script

Tags: python, mysql, shell

I need to add the following 2 columns to all the tables in my model (mwb file)

- `created`
- `updated`

Because there are many tables to be modified, instead of doing it manually I found the [following script](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/06/mysql-workbench-script-for-adding-columns-to-all-tables-in-a-model/)

```
# get a reference to the schema in the model. This will get the 1st schema in it.
schema = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0]
# iterate through all tables
for table in schema.tables:
    # create a new column object and set its name
    column = grt.classes.db_mysql_Column()
    column.name = "created"
    # add it to the table
    table.addColumn(column)
    # set the datatype of the column
    column.setParseType("TIMESTAMP", None)
    column.defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

    # same thing for the update_time column
    column = grt.classes.db_mysql_Column()
    column.name = "updated"
    table.addColumn(column)
    column.setParseType("TIMESTAMP", None)
```

The script is working fine (I added the columns to all my table) but those columns are added at the end of each table.

I want to add them in 2nd and 3rd position, right after the primary key in 1st position.

I looked at the [db_mysql_Column](http://wb.fabforce.eu/doc/globals/classdb__mysql___column-members.html) definition, but I cannot see any data relevant to the position.

Also, the [addColumn](http://wb.fabforce.eu/doc/globals/classdb___table.html#a6c3e505e9f8396529b62bc59b06639a9) method does not allows an overload with some sort of position

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: the order of columns in a table doesn't matter.

Comment: I know @vkp, but seeing the model in a graphic way (EER Diagram of mySQL Workbench) I think it is more readable to have the same 2 columns at the same position for each table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use python, but using this information:
[MySQL syntax error using python to add column to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036067/mysql-syntax-error-using-python-to-add-column-to-a-table)
you should be able to do this:

`ALTER TABLE`mytable`ADD`newcol`INT NOT NULL AFTER`idcol`;`

Using the `cursor.execute( query )`

Personally, for 1 of's, I would use sh to loop through a list of table names and write out the alter stmts to a file which I would then execute via mysql client. I'm kind of lazy that way.